# Java sort HashMap values which are List<Value>

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, comparator

I got the HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, List<Value>> facetsInCategories = new HashMap<>();
```

I need to sort the List of Values inside the value of this HashMap. The value in the list has four fields, and I need to sort the list by the "translatedValue" String. That is why I put "getTranslatedValue" in custom comparator. Here is Value object fields:

```
public String name;
public int count;
private String translatedValue;
private String translation;
```

And here is what I tried:

```
for (List<Value> value : facetsInCategories.values()) {
    Collections.sort(value, new Comparator<Value>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Value o1, Value o2) {
                return o1.getTranslatedValue().compareTo(o2.getTranslatedValue());
            }
    });
}
```

I've been doing this for couple of hours now, so I thought you may advise somehow on that.

Comment: What is the result you are getting and what is the result you are expecting?

Comment: I would expect above code to sort your Value-objects according to the result of String-compareTo of their 'translatedValue'... is this happening already?

Comment: Why do you put the list back on the Map? there is no need for that. Sorting should work file.

Comment: what I am worried about right now is that for (List<Value> value : facetsInCategories.values()) throws an error on the second iteration. This should not happen in my opinion.

Comment: facetsInCategories.put("test", value); was just for tests, I deleted it from the question right now.

Comment: Try this in the return of your comapre (more Safe) : `return (o1 == null || o2 == null || o1.getTranslatedValue() == null || o2.getTranslatedValue() == null) ? -1 : o1.getTranslatedValue().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getTranslatedValue());`

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine. Collections.sort will sort the lists in place.

Why do you need this line?

```
facetsInCategories.put("test", value);
```

The lists are already added in the hashmap. And they will be sorted where they are.

From null-safety point of view, you are assuming this will never be null:

```
o1.getTranslatedValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line and it should do the trick:

```
facetsInCategories.put("test", value);
```

Comment: facetsInCategories.put("test", value); was just for tests, I deleted it from the question right now. What I am worried about right now is that for (List<Value> value : facetsInCategories.values()) throws an error on the second iteration. This should not happen in my opinion.